# Angular 8 not working in IE11 and how to set angular application es6/es2015

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

When I run my app in IE browser I get this error:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

My app works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: IE doens't support es6/es2015 syntax (e.g. lambda function arrows) so you can't use es6 as a target. Set the target to es5 in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: i am use target es2015

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable polyfills to make most of the functionality work in IE.

Comment: i have already enable polyfills

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362323/angular-8-project-not-working-in-microsoft-edge-and-ie11/57368223#57368223):

By default in angular version 8, differential loading for `ng build` is enabled. However for `ng test` and `ng serve`, it only generates a single ES2015 build which cannot run in IE11.

You could refer to the following steps to configure ES5 with angular 8 application, which will make the application work in IE11.

```
Create a new tsconfig tsconfig-es5.app.json next to tsconfig.app.json with the below contents:

    { 
     "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
     "compilerOptions": { 
     "target": "es5"   
      }
    }

In your angular.json add two new configuration section (es5 node) under the build and serve target to provide a new tsconfig.

    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            ...
    },
    "configurations": {
    "production": {
        ...
    },
    "es5": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
    }
    }
    },
    "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        ...
    },
    "configurations": {
    "production": {
    ...
    },
    "es5": {
        "browserTarget": "<your application name>:build:es5"
    }
    }
    },

You can then run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

    ng serve --configuration es5
```

Besides, the browserslist file content as below:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

You can then run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

```
    ng serve --configuration es5
```