# Kendo Grid - vendor.js SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular8

I'm currently using Kendo Grid in my project. In IE11 it throws me SCRIPT1002 error.

**package.json**

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^4.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-gauges": "^3.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^4.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^2.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^4.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.3",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.1.0",
```

[image]

If you see in the above image it has mentioned a line, if I just click on that line I'm having the below code snippet.

```
const insertDefaultFilter = (index, rootFilter, filter) => {
rootFilter = (rootFilter || { filters: [], logic: "and" });
rootFilter.filters[index] = filter;
return filter;
```

As you see it uses arrow function. Since the Arrow function is not supported in IE11, I think it throws me this error.

**What have I tried?**

1. In tsconfig.json, I have tried changing the target to es5
2. I have imported the necessary polyfills in polyfills.ts file
3. I also try to downgrade the version of the library but it still remains the same

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where does `vendor.js` come from? Is it actually Typescript or is it a JavaScript source? It doesn't look like compiled Typescript.

Comment: @Pointy It is TypeScript. I have mentioned once after the compilation, if I try to load the site in IE, it points me the respective error at vendor.js

Comment: If it starts from typescript then changing the target to es5 would work. Are you sure you're completely rebuilding the project?

Comment: @Pointy Yes I have tried both ng build and ng build --proto. But no luck still.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362323/angular-8-project-not-working-in-microsoft-edge-and-ie11/57368223#57368223 try this

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yea I have also tried the specified points. Still no luck